# Wemos D1 Interrupt Deepsleep

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am working on project that involves using the Wemos D1. If I put my Wemos D1 into deepsleep mode. Is it possible to create an interrupt to wake up my Wemos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly it is not possible to doing it internally.

In deep sleep mode CH_PD goes low and making it high the only thing to wake the chip up.

But, you can do it via an external event of another trigger like rtc, microcontroller or a button etc.

Comment: thanks for the clarification... so to be clear.. i can write attach an interrupt and wake up the WeMOs just like I would with an Arduino Uno?

Comment: You mean triggering your wifi chip from an uno? Could you please share the setup details?

Comment: i did some searching.. i found this  [link] (https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1488). basically, i am thinking in the code make the chip sleep forever, deepsleep(0),adding a switch in the NO position between GPIO16-> RST.. i also need a pull down resistor.. thoughts?

Comment: Correct. Triggering GPIO 16 that is what you need.